# New WP page template, adjusting bootstrap, now a few things not working

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

Made a WP page template based on a default template, adjusting just the bootstrap details for the main content area width and the sidebar.  It works great as seen here: 
[https://www.bodyzone.com/certified-posture-exercise-professional/][1]

But

1) the header drop-down menus no longer work - "Your Posture" should have 4-5 links underneath and the Shop should show a dropdown for 2 pages.

2) items listed on other pages not using the new template are displayed incorrectly. Products are displayed in 2 columns with the images blown up and distorted.  They should be in 4 columns, smaller.

I created maybe 10 new pages using the new template but nowhere else is the template applied.  But it seems as if my making this has altered everything else on the site.

New Page Template:

```
get_header(); ?>

<!-- Begin page content -->

    <main role="main">
        <div id="content">
<!-- Page content -->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
           <style scoped>
           p { font-size:1.9em; }
           </style>
  <section> 

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) :    the_post(); ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
         <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>

   <figure class="page-wp-post-image">

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for page ?>

   <figcaption><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?

   </figcaption>
   </figure>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php edit_post_link('<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit', '<p>',
 '</p>'); ?>

      </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

      <article>
         <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
      </article>

<?php endif; ?>
  </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>        
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The original bootstrap div class for the default page - content - is this
`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-push-2">`

for the sidebar it's this 
`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-10">`

I inherited the site, and only have a passing understanding of bootstrap - but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: OK saw in some other comments about how W3 Total Cache messes with some bootstrap elements. I disabled the JS minify settings in W3TC and got my dropdown menus back.  However, there's still the issue of products  pages displaying using 2 large columns rather than smaller 4 columns.

Comment: I disabled Minify and now have my columns back the way they're supposed to be.  So I guess it wasn't the template after all.  Carry on.